# Using LINQ GroupBy chains to produce a multi-level hierarchy with aggregations

Tags: c#, linq

I happened to do this and thought of asking about the under-the-hood guarantees about O(n), order stability and enumerator instances that are involved.

I understand that the number of enumerator inflection points per aggregation, such as counts and durations, varies depending on the actual distribution of children to parent levels, but isn't it at least true that each Record is only enumerated ONCE per aggregate?

In this example, we have 3 aggregations and 3 hierarchy levels to aggregate over, hence O(9n) ~ O(n).

LINQ GroupBy Questions:

1. Is GroupBy documented to be both linear complexity and stable ordering, or is it just how Microsoft .NET's impl does it? I don't have any particular suspicion it may be non-linear, just asking out of curiosity.
2. It seems like the number of enumerators instantiated should always be linear with the number of parent nodes seen in the hierarchy, true?
3. No leaf or non-leaf is enumerated more than once during the same aggregation stat and level, true? Because each node is only the child of one parent in some single "result".

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    namespace NestedGroupBy
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            struct Record
            {
                // cat->subcat->event is the composite 3-tier key
                private readonly string category;
                private readonly string subcategory;
                private readonly string ev;
                private readonly double duration;

                public Record(string category, string subcategory, string ev, double duration)
                {
                    this.category = category;
                    this.subcategory = subcategory;
                    this.ev = ev;
                    this.duration = duration;
                }

                public string Category { get { return category; } }
                public string Subcategory { get { return subcategory; } }
                public string Event { get { return ev; } }
                public double Duration { get { return duration; } }
            }

            static readonly IList<Record> Rec1 = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Record>
            (new[] {
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "Security", "ReadSocket", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadMetadata", "ReadDirectory", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadMetadata", "ReadDirectory", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadMetadata", "ReadDirectory", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadMetadata", "ReadSize", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadMetadata", "ReadSize", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadMetadata", "ReadSize", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "ReadKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "ReadKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "ReadKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "ReadKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "CacheKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "CacheKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "CheckKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "CheckKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "ReadKey", "CheckKeyAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "WriteKey", "CheckPermissions", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "WriteKey", "CheckOwner", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "WriteKey", "InheritPermissions", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "WriteKey", "ValidateKey", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Registry", "WriteKey", "RecacheKey", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "WriteData", "FlushData", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "WriteData", "WriteBuffer", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "WriteData", "WritePermissions", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadData", "CheckDataBuffer", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadData", "ReadBuffer", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("File", "ReadData", "ReadPermissions", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "Security", "ReadSocket", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "Security", "ReadSocket", 0.0145),
                 new Record ("Network", "SecurityCheck", "ReadAcl", 0.0145),
            });

            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
                // Perform one big sort to order all child rungs properly
                var s = Rec1.OrderBy(
                    r => r,
                    Comparer<Record>.Create(
                        (x, y) =>
                        {
                            int c = x.Category.CompareTo(y.Category);
                            if (c != 0) return c;
                            c = x.Subcategory.CompareTo(y.Subcategory);
                            if (c != 0) return c;
                            return x.Event.CompareTo(y.Event);
                        }));

                // This query enumerates bottom-up (in the key hierarchy-sense), 
                // then proceedes to each higher summary (parent) level and retains
                // the "result" collection of its children determined by the preceding GroupBy.
                //
                // This is so each level can later step down into its own children for looping. 
                // And the leaf durations, immediate child counts and leaf event counts are already calculated as well.
                //
                // I think this is O(n), since each record does not get repeatedly scanned for different levels of the same accumulation stat.
                // But under-the-hood there may be much grainy processing like enumerator instantiation, depending on child count density.
                var q = s
                    .GroupBy(
                        r => new { Category = r.Category, Subcategory = r.Subcategory, Event = r.Event },
                        (key, result) => {
                            int c = result.Count();
                            return new
                            {
                                LowKey = key,
                                // at this lowest summary level only, 
                                // the hierarchical (immediate child) count is the same as the event (leaf) count
                                LowChildCount = c,
                                LowEventCount = c,
                                LowDuration = result.Sum(x => x.Duration),
                                LowChildren = result
                            };
                        })
                        .GroupBy(
                            r => new { Category = r.LowKey.Category, Subcategory = r.LowKey.Subcategory },
                                (key, result) => new {
                                    MidKey = key,
                                    MidChildCount = result.Count(),
                                    MidEventCount = result.Sum(x => x.LowEventCount),
                                    MidDuration = result.Sum(x => x.LowDuration),
                                    MidChildren = result
                                })
                                .GroupBy(
                                    r => new { Category = r.MidKey.Category },
                                    (key, result) => new {
                                        HighKey = key,
                                        HighChildCount = result.Count(),
                                        HighEventCount = result.Sum(x => x.MidEventCount),
                                        HighDuration = result.Sum(x => x.MidDuration),
                                        HighChildren = result
                                    });


                foreach (var high in q)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{high.HighKey.Category} child#={high.HighChildCount} event#={high.HighEventCount} duration={high.HighDuration}");
                    foreach (var mid in high.HighChildren)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"  {mid.MidKey.Subcategory} child#={mid.MidChildCount} event#={high.HighEventCount} duration={mid.MidDuration}");
                        foreach (var low in mid.MidChildren)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"    {low.LowKey.Event} child#={low.LowChildCount} event#={high.HighEventCount} duration={low.LowDuration}");
                            foreach (var leaf in low.LowChildren)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"      >> {leaf.Category}/{leaf.Subcategory}/{leaf.Event} duration={leaf.Duration}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Review the source code of [GroupBy](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d6d5ab3816f9dd7e) and that shall answer all the questions you have

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with reviewing the implementation of `Enumerable.GroupBy` from the MS source code:

**GroupBy**

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>
(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
 Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, 
 Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, 
 Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector)
{
  return new GroupedEnumerable<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>(source, 
                                                                 keySelector, 
                                                                 elementSelector, 
                                                                 resultSelector, null);
}
```

**GroupedEnumerable**

```
internal class GroupedEnumerable<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult> : IEnumerable<TResult>{
    IEnumerable<TSource> source;
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector;
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector;
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer;
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector;

    public GroupedEnumerable(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer){
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (keySelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector");
        if (elementSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("elementSelector");
        if (resultSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("resultSelector");
        this.source = source;
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
        this.elementSelector = elementSelector;
        this.comparer = comparer;
        this.resultSelector = resultSelector;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator(){
        Lookup<TKey, TElement> lookup = Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Create<TSource>(source, keySelector, elementSelector, comparer);
        return lookup.ApplyResultSelector(resultSelector).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(){
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Important point is it internally use the `LookUp` Data Structure, which provides the `O(1)` Lookup for the Key, so its internally Enumerating through all the records and for every record adding the data to `LookUp`, which is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TValue>>`

**Now Your specific Questions**

> Is GroupBy documented to be both linear complexity and stable ordering, or is it just how Microsoft .NET's impl does it? I don't have any particular suspicion it may be non-linear, just asking out of curiosity.

Design and the code suggest O(N) at the top level, but surely it depends upon the Element Selection, if that further does a `O(N)` operation, that would automatically make the complexity `O(N^2)` or more

> It seems like the number of enumerators instantiated should always be linear with the number of parent nodes seen in the hierarchy, true?

Yes it is just a single enumerator at the top level

> No leaf or non-leaf is enumerated more than once during the same aggregation stat and level, true? Because each node is only the child of one parent in some single "result".

By non  leaf nodes I assume you are referring to the Nested data, so this is dependent on your model design, but if each element has its separate copy of nested data as expected, not shared / reference, then I don't see why an element will be touched more than once, it is enumeration for the specific sub / child data

**Few more details**

- In your case you are composing the `GroupBy` Query, thus result of one query acts as an input for another one, in terms of complexity this is more like `O(N) + O(N) + O(N)` ~ `O(N)`, but inside each one of them you are doing at least 1 O(N) operation, thus the overall complexity by virtue of your nested design shall be `O(N^2)` not `O(N)`
- If you have deep nested data, then instead on concatenated `GroupBy`, `SelectMany`, which flattens the data is a better choice, as its less complex to to run final aggregation on the flattened data